# Mount a directory on a host EC2 instance from within a running docker container using beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been stuck on this for far too long...

I am using elastic-beanstalk to run a docker container which I upload as a Dockerfile. There is a formatted mounted AWS volume on the host EC2 instance. I want to mount this volume in the docker container running on this EC2 host.

I can achieve what I want locally (without AWS) using:

`docker run -v /host_dir:/container_dir -d --name container_name image_name`

However, when using elastic-beanstalk I cannot explicitly specify the arguments to `docker run`. Instead I must use a Dockerrn.aws.json file which is uploaded along with the Dockerfile. This is what I *think* should be in this file:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Volumes": [{
      "HostDirectory": "/host_dir",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/container_dir"
  }]
}
```

However it doesn't even create the `container_dir` directory on the docker container, let alone map it to `host_dir`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this myself.

The docker daemon running on the EC2 doesn't see the AWS volume if it was mounted after it started. I shh'd into the EC2 instance and restarted the docker daemon `service docker restart`. The docker container then had the directories mounted as desired.